# Moodle Configurable Report MySQL

Tags: mysql, report, moodle

I would like to get a report with usernames and user cohorts together with the status of the scorm activites on the site. I have found two SQL snippets of code but unfortunately I have no idea how to combine them to achieve what I want. I would be really grateful if there was someone who is able to help me with it.

1. Users and cohorts:

```
     SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, h.idnumber, h.name
     FROM prefix_cohort AS h
     JOIN prefix_cohort_members AS hm ON h.id = hm.cohortid
     JOIN prefix_user AS u ON hm.userid = u.id
     ORDER BY u.firstname
```

2. List of users with the scorm statuses:

   ```
    SELECT
    u.username AS 'User',
    c.shortname AS 'Course',
    m.name AS Activitytype,
    CASE
    WHEN cm.module = 1 THEN (SELECT a1.name FROM prefix_assign a1            WHERE a1.id = cm.instance)
    WHEN cm.module = 2 THEN (SELECT a2.name FROM prefix_assignment a2    WHERE a2.id = cm.instance)
    WHEN cm.module = 3 THEN (SELECT a3.name FROM prefix_book a3               WHERE a3.id = cm.instance)
    WHEN cm.module = 4 THEN (SELECT a4.name FROM prefix_chat a4                WHERE a4.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 5 THEN (SELECT a5.name FROM prefix_choice a5            WHERE a5.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 6 THEN (SELECT a6.name FROM prefix_data a6                WHERE a6.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 7 THEN (SELECT a7.name FROM prefix_feedback a7        WHERE a7.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 8 THEN (SELECT a8.name FROM prefix_folder a8              WHERE a8.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 9 THEN (SELECT a9.name FROM prefix_forum a9              WHERE a9.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 10 THEN (SELECT a10.name FROM prefix_glossary a10         WHERE a10.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 11 THEN (SELECT a11.name FROM prefix_imscp  a11           WHERE a11.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 12 THEN (SELECT a12.name FROM prefix_label a12              WHERE a12.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 13 THEN (SELECT a13.name FROM prefix_lesson a13            WHERE a13.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 14 THEN (SELECT a14.name FROM prefix_lti a14                    WHERE a14.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 15 THEN (SELECT a15.name FROM prefix_page a15               WHERE a15.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 16 THEN (SELECT a16.name FROM prefix_quiz  a16               WHERE a16.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 17 THEN (SELECT a17.name FROM prefix_resource a17         WHERE a17.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 18 THEN (SELECT a18.name FROM prefix_scorm a18             WHERE a18.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 19 THEN (SELECT a19.name FROM prefix_survey a19             WHERE a19.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 20 THEN (SELECT a20.name FROM prefix_url a20                      WHERE a20.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 21 THEN (SELECT a21.name FROM prefix_wiki a21                    WHERE a21.id = cm.instance)
        WHEN cm.module = 22 THEN (SELECT a22.name FROM prefix_workshop a22           WHERE a22.id = cm.instance)
    END AS Actvityname,
    # cm.section AS Coursesection,
    CASE
        WHEN cm.completion = 0 THEN '0 None'
        WHEN cm.completion = 1 THEN '1 Self'
        WHEN cm.completion = 2 THEN '2 Auto'
    END AS Activtycompletiontype,
    CASE
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 0 THEN 'In Progress'
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 1 THEN 'Completed'
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 2 THEN 'Completed with Pass'
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 3 THEN 'Completed with Fail'
       ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS 'Progress',
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cmc.timemodified), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS 'When'
    FROM prefix_course_modules_completion cmc
    JOIN prefix_user u ON cmc.userid = u.id
    JOIN prefix_course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id
    JOIN prefix_course c ON cm.course = c.id
    JOIN prefix_modules m ON cm.module = m.id
    # skip the predefined admin AND guest USER
    WHERE u.id > 2
    # config reports filters
    %%FILTER_USERS:u.username%%
    %%FILTER_SEARCHTEXT:m.name:~%%
    %%FILTER_STARTTIME:cmc.timemodified:>%% %%FILTER_ENDTIME:cmc.timemodified:<%%
     
    ORDER BY u.username
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id AS userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, 
    h.id AS cohortid, h.name AS cohortname, h.idnumber AS cohortidnumber,
    c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    s.id AS scormid, s.name AS scormname,
    CASE
        WHEN cm.completion = 0 THEN '0 None' /* COMPLETION_TRACKING_NONE */
        WHEN cm.completion = 1 THEN '1 Manual' /* COMPLETION_TRACKING_MANUAL */
        WHEN cm.completion = 2 THEN '2 Auto' /* COMPLETION_TRACKING_AUTOMATIC */
    END AS Activtycompletiontype,
    CASE
        WHEN cmc.completionstate = 0 THEN 'In Progress' /* COMPLETION_INCOMPLETE */
        WHEN cmc.completionstate = 1 THEN 'Completed' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE */
        WHEN cmc.completionstate = 2 THEN 'Completed with Pass' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE_PASS */
        WHEN cmc.completionstate = 3 THEN 'Completed with Fail' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE_FAIL */
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS progress,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cmc.timemodified), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS 'When'
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_cohort_members hm ON hm.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_cohort h ON h.id = hm.cohortid
JOIN mdl_course_modules_completion cmc ON cmc.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON cm.id = cmc.coursemoduleid
JOIN mdl_modules m ON m.id = cm.module AND m.name = 'scorm'
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = cm.course
JOIN mdl_scorm s ON s.id = cm.instance
```